# Why doesnt MSDSM device show up for MPIO with Powershell query?

Tags: windows, powershell

When adding a Device to MPIO in the MPIO Window, if you query that device in Powershell it doesnt show up.  However, if you create the device with Powershell, then query, it does.

What is going on here?

[image: msdsm mpio query not working]